# Validating '%' and '(' on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, validation

Greetings all. I have the following function to validate input depending if is numeric, alpha, alphanumeric and email:

```
  function permite(e, permitidos) {

    var key = e.keyCode || e.which;

    //Validate if its an arrow or delete button
    if((key == 46) || (key == 8) || (key >= 37 && key <= 40))
        return true;

    var keychar = String.fromCharCode(key);

    switch(permitidos) {
        case 'num':
            permitidos = /^[0-9]$/;
            break;
        case 'car':
            permitidos = /^[\sa-zA-Z]$/;
            break;
        case 'num_car':
            permitidos = /^[\sa-zA-Z0-9]$/;
            break;
        case 'correo':
            permitidos = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._\-+@]$/;
            break;
    }

    return permitidos.test(keychar);


 }
```

The var names are in spanish but its an easy function to understand.

The problem is the following. The keycode for '%' is 37 the same than the left arrow and the keycode for '(' is 40 the same than the right arrow. So my function is not validating '%' and '(' and it sucks. I dont know what to do, please help.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>The `keypress` event doesn't fire for arrow and delete keys, so you can just remove your `if` statement.</strike>  Darn you FireFox!

You are mixing up `keyCode` and `charCode`, which is understandable because `event.keyCode` actually contains `charCode` for `keyPress` events, unlike `keydown` and `keyup`.  The keyCode for `(` is 57 (same as for `9` - those characters are on the same key).  Its charCode is 40.  Arrow keys don't have charCodes, so they don't fire `keypress` events.  (Except in FireFox... Argh!)

Your best bet is to use the `keydown` event and look for `keyCode` rather than `charCode`, checking for shift keys when necessary.  You'll have to manually map keyCodes to characters when the shift key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly OT (apologies) but you may want to look at one of the Javascript libraries out there, for example JQuery; almost all of them come with (or have) libraries for "validating input".

For example: if you were using JQuery you may consider the "Validation" plugin - http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Answer (score 0):

Check for whether the shift key is being pressed as well by checking [event.shiftKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.shiftKey):

```
//Validate if its an arrow or delete button
if((key == 46) || (key == 8) || (key >= 37 && key <= 40 && !e.shiftKey))
    return true;
```

Another option (depending on your application) is to handle the `keydown` event instead of the `keypress` event, which won't result in overlapping key codes.

Comment: This only works on keyboards where the user must depress `SHIFT` in order to produce `%` or `(`.